# I found a really nice style for disfcrete math cheat sheet I want to replicate

Tags: math-mode, pdf

[image]So I have an exam coming up and it is open book, but I want to make a personalised cheat sheet for the course so I know where everything is. I found an amazing one online. I have all the tex, dvi, makefile and pdf. How do I go about making my own version of this in latex? I am struggling with importing all the tex into a single Main.tex.

Is there a way to reverse engineer this to compile as one pdf and be able to change the content to my liking?

Alternatively, does anyone have a similar template that I could use?? I would hugely appreciate any support!!

Comment: The email address of the author is literally on the page.  Why don't you ask him?

Comment: Oh, an email will in fact not be very helpful: https://web.archive.org/web/20020818161636/http://bit.csc.lsu.edu/news/news200206121.html

Comment: Ha!  It's still available on the TUG TeX showcase website: https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/#math (Direct link to the source: https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat-20131114.tar.gz)

Comment: Okay so I would just like to note that I am new to Latex, clearly. I have all the tex documents like I said in my post. But how do you go about compiling them into one main.tex file? There is around 30, do I '\include{}' all of them? This is a genuine question I have, and I am looking for an answer Alessandro. If having the original source makes this so easy then suggest a solution please.

Comment: Henri, like I mentioned, I have the source already. Thank you I am aware of this, I am after a solution to the issue of compilation. I am not sure how to go about compiling all of those seperate .tex files into one singlular main.tex which I can then run.

Comment: From the README: *It's all done in TeX, except for one postscript picture.
It needs to print on a PostScript printer. I can send you
the TeX source if you want, but it's messy.* Therefore, your concern is justified.
Nonetheless, consider having a look at the `makefile`.

Comment: I'd suggest to update the title of  you question and update its body with the findings reported in the comments, so that it does not appear as a "Do It For Me" question.
The real question is: *how to tackle the compilation of this (messy) source?*

Comment: In light of the above, I'm retracting my close vote

Comment: I tried the command `pdftex t1` and the `t1.pdf` is sucessfully generated. Similarly: `pdftex t2`, `pdftex t3`. Notice: the files are plain TeX sources, no LaTeX. The pictures in `t4` and `t5` are not processed becuase there are realized by `\special` primitive (obsolete when PDF is generated directly by pdftex). Works: `tex t4` and `xdvi t4`.

Comment: @Ventti I installed `fig2dev` and `groff` to be able to compile the pictures and then I typed `make`.  This creates `cheat.dvi` without problems for me.  Then I ran `dvipdfmx cheat.dvi` to generate a PDF.  This doesn't quite work but that is due to the way `ecsher.ps` (sic!) is included and has only little to do with TeX.  The PDF is still generated and viewable but `ecsher.ps` is missing.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate all your help. But I don't see why you closed this question Henri? Sorry that this seems too basic of an issue for you however, allesandro is right @"how to tackle the compilation of this (messy) source?". I do appreciate all those steps everyone, I ended up creating my own cheatsheet based off the Latex cheatsheet on their website but for discrete maths.